# Eclipse ADT (android Pugin) refuses to find images in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, adt

Off the bat, version information:

- Eclipse: Juno Release, build 20120614-1722
- Android: 4.4
- ADT: 20.0.0v201206242043-391819

There are many, many questions on SO regarding the various `res/drawable` folders (standard, `drawable-hdpi`, `-mdpi`, `-ldpi`, `-xhdpi`) and on whether it's necessary to create the standard drawable folder if it doesn't exist, where Android/ADT/Eclipse will look for the `@drawable/*` files, etc. However, my question seems to not have been answered thus far.

It's a pretty striaghtforward problem. To put it simply, I placed a file name 'starbg.png' in my `drawable-hdpi` folder, then used the qualifier `@drawable/starbg.png` in a layout `xml` file. However, Eclipse is throwing an error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' 
with value '@drawable/starbg.png').
```

Why? Unsure. I have tried the following solutions based on SO questions, all without success:

- Cleaning the project (multiple times)
- Creating a `res/drawable` folder (as one was not auto-generated by my version of ADT) and adding the image there
- Copying the file into every single related folder
- Renaming the file to `star_bg.png`
- Restarting Eclipse

The project is not complicated. It's an incredibly simple setup, with 2 views, one of which has nothing more than a `LinearLayout` with an `android:background` attribute (with layout and orientation info, of course), the other of which works like a charm.

So I'm stumped. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you specify your resource, it should not include the file extension. that is, a resource file,

```
drawable/starbg.png
```

should be referenced as,

```
@drawable/starbg
```

e.g.,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@drawable/starbg"
  ...>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well. That was stupidly simple. I'll mark you correct in 5 mins.

Comment: sometimes you just need another pair of eyes :)